# How to get permanent access token for microsoft outlook api

Tags: php, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have set scopes as follows:

```
openid profile 
offline_access 
User.Read Mail.ReadWrite 
Mail.Send 
Calendars.ReadWrite 
Contacts.Read
```

I want a permanent access token so that I don't need to login again and again.
Help me out, how can I use a token in the login api to get permanent access?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about [Azure Active Directory Authentication with OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios). If that's the case the token you get back at the end of the authentication flow should be re-usable until the token lifetime expires. Can you show us your code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Graph API provides two authentication flow:

## 1. [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user)

## 2. [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)

**If you want to run the Outlook API in background service**(not all app need user signed-in, based on actual demand), you can use the authentication flow #2. By using this way, end user do not need to request Token explicitly, so it look like permanent access token, until the Microsoft/Azure need the admin consent again.

**If you want to run the Outlook API just for signed-in user**, you can use the authentication flow #1. After get an access Token, store the access Token and Refresh Token in the Token-cache and use the refresh Token to request new Token while the access token lifetime expires. If both access/refresh token have expired, the user need to sign-in again to re-grant permission.

Comment: Yes i did the same as your suggestion  for signed in user. I saved token refresh token and expiry time in db and i fetch the refresh token and then create new access token.
i am using rest api so i preferred  db option rather than cache.

Comment: Even the refresh token still have expiry time, so we can just archieve pseudo- permanent access

Comment: @user77232 I've fixed the broken links.